# Java/Spring Boot 415 Unsupported Media Type Error with POST request

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot

"I wrote a POST method that saves data from the form.html to the database. It correctly saves the data in the database, but when I run my endpoint in the browser (I tried Chrome, Opera, Edge), I still encounter the **415 issue**. After clicking on the 'Continue' button, I only see a 415 error. In Postman, I receive a status **200 OK**. I tried Chrome DevTools, and I get the same result: status 200 and redirection to the appropriate endpoint after all. Do you know where problem can be ?

```
Here is the related javascript code.
```

```
function sendData() {
  const form = document.getElementById('form');
  const insuranceSelect = form.querySelector('#insurance');
  const selectedInsurance = insuranceSelect.options[insuranceSelect.selectedIndex].value;

  const data = {
    "firstName": form.querySelector('#firstName').value,
    "lastName": form.querySelector('#lastName').value,
    "email": form.querySelector('#email').value,
    "password": form.querySelector('#password').value,
    "birthDate": form.querySelector('#birthDate').value, // ISO 8601 format
    "birthNumber": form.querySelector('#birthNumber').value,
    "phoneNumber": form.querySelector('#phoneNumber').value,
    "insuranceCompany": selectedInsurance
  };


  fetch('/Insurance/register', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Origin': 'http://localhost:8080'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(data)
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log('Response status code:', response.status);

      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error(`Registration failed with status: ${response.status}`);
      }

      console.log('Registration successful!');
      window.location.href = "/Insurance/login";

    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.error('Error during registration:', error.message);
    });
}
```

POST METHOD  this method save correctly data with status 200 in postman ...

```
@PostMapping(value = "/register", consumes = {"application/json"},produces = {"application/json"})
public ResponseEntity<?> registerUser(@RequestBody  RegistrationForm registrationForm) {

    System.out.println(registrationForm.toString());

    Client client = clientService.createClient(registrationForm);

    ClientDAO dao = new ClientDAO(sessionFactory);
    if (validateClient(client)) {
        if (dao.saveClient(client)) {

            return ResponseEntity.ok().body("Registration was successful!");

        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Failed to save the client.");
        }
    } else {
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Please provide all necessary information to complete registration");
    }
}
```

[headers in postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLYWl.png)

[request body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UPrDi.png)

I was trying this in postman and registration was successful with status 200, also in chrome DevTools
[devTools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2mEXD.png)
[error in browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuJEk.png)

Related logs Content-Type '**application/x-www-form-urlencoded**' is not supported  , i set content type in JS **application/json** also in post method.

```
2024-01-14T21:53:04.249+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.j.d.DriverManagerDataSource          : Creating new JDBC DriverManager Connection to [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/insuranceDatabase]
2024-01-14T21:53:04.270+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : POST "/Insurance/register", parameters={masked}
2024-01-14T21:53:04.277+01:00  WARN 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException: Content-Type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' is not supported]
2024-01-14T21:53:04.278+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 415 UNSUPPORTED_MEDIA_TYPE
2024-01-14T21:53:04.281+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : "ERROR" dispatch for POST "/Insurance/error", parameters={masked}
2024-01-14T21:53:04.285+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped to org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController#errorHtml(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse)
2024-01-14T21:53:04.286+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Opening JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2024-01-14T21:53:04.294+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Selected 'text/html' given [text/html, text/html;q=0.8]
2024-01-14T21:53:04.295+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2024-01-14T21:53:04.295+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Exiting from "ERROR" dispatch, status 415
2024-01-14T21:53:04.475+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Using 'application/json', given [application/json] and supported [application/json]
2024-01-14T21:53:04.477+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.w.s.m.m.a.HttpEntityMethodProcessor  : Writing ["Registration was successful!"]
2024-01-14T21:53:04.479+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.j.s.OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor : Closing JPA EntityManager in OpenEntityManagerInViewInterceptor
2024-01-14T21:53:04.480+01:00 DEBUG 13352 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed 200 OK
```

Comment: I don't find anything odd about the code you mention yet. The REST endpoint seems to be correctly implemented in Spring and all the parameters seem to be in order in your javascript code using fetch, which makes me ask if this problem is related to the html itself? This is why it would be great, if possible, if you could also share some or all of the html code. I'm thinking about the `method` and the `action` attributes.

Comment: <form  class="needs-validation" id="form" novalidate method="POST" action="/Insurance/register" enctype="application/json">    But today i tried another solution with @RequestParameters, without convert to Json and this solution worked.  After two days of searching where problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I think I see the problem. Thank you for sharing your html form code. In the attribute action you are specifying the same endpoint as your javascript call. This means that when you configure atribute `action` to be `/Insurance/register` you are actually performing a double request. The first request gets done and the other one gets done too. So, that is already a problem in itself. You probably don't need those attributes anyways, because you are using `fetch` and so it is really not necessary to perform any action. By default, that form with that `action` and that `POST` method will send a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` request type leading up to the `415 Unsupported Media Type` error, when clicking on the submit button. And the actual request you want to perform also gets performed. So you need to do something else other than the traditional form submit in this case, if you want to keep using that `fetch` function. You can find more information about this on the [MDN Sending and Retrieving Form Data Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms/Sending_and_retrieving_form_data).

Comment: Thank your for your answer, i tried just remove this attributes from html tag but still result was same :/ i rather solve this problem with @RequestParam ,without json ...

Comment: I think you'll run into the same problem, because it seems like you are still making a double request. JSON is also a standard. The actual code to solve this problem isn't a one answer problem. The concept behind it is. So the idea is that, if you want to use that fetch function, then something else needs to change in your code. The removal of attributes is one step, but there are quite a lot of solutions for this. The whole point is not to submit this form and use something else. Here is a good example: https://dev.to/amjadmh73/submit-html-forms-to-json-apis-easily-137l